# python comparing two lists and retaining second list index

Tags: python

I am taking a user input of "components" splitting it into a list and comparing those components to a list of available components generated from column A of a google sheet. Then what I am attempting to do is return the cell value from column G corresponding the Column A index. Then repeat this for all input values.

So far I am getting the first value just fine but I'm obviously missing something to get it to cycle back and to the remaining user input components. I tried some stuff using itertools but wasn't able to get the results I wanted. I have a feeling I will facepalm when I discover the solution to this through here or on my own.

```
        mix = select.split(',')     # sets user input to string and sparates elements
        ws = s.worksheet("Details") # opens table in google sheet
        c_list = ws.col_values(1)   # sets column A to a list
        modifier = [""] * len(mix)  # sets size of list based on user input
        list = str(c_list).lower()

        for i in range(len(mix)):
            if str(mix[i]).lower() in str(c_list).lower():
                for j in range(len(c_list)):
                    if str(mix[i]).lower() == str(c_list[j]).lower():
                        modifier[i] = ws.cell(j+1,7).value  # get value of cell from Column G corresponding to Column A for component name
        print(mix)
        print(modifier)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over complicating the code by writing `C` like code.
I have changed all the loops you had to a simpler single loop, I have also left comments above each code line to explain what it does.

```py
# Here we use .lower() to lower case all the values in select
# before splitting them and adding them to the list "mix"
mix = select.lower().split(",")

ws = s.worksheet("Details")

# Here we used a list comprehension to create a list of the "column A"
# values but all in lower case
c_list = [cell.lower() for cell in ws.col_values(1)]

modifier = [""] * len(mix)

# Here we loop through every item in mix, but also keep a count of iterations
# we have made, which we will use later to add the "column G" element to the
# corresponding location in the list "modifier"
for i, value in enumerate(mix):
    # Here we check if the value exists in the c_list
    if value in c_list:
        # If we find the value in the c_list, we get the index of the value in c_list
        index = c_list.index(value)
        # Here we add the value of column G that has an index of "index + 1" to
        # the modifier list at the same location of the value in list "mix"
        modifier[i] = ws.cell(index + 1, 7).value
```

Comment: Yeah I'm kind of teaching myself little by little. This does look much more clean. I am however getting the same output when I display the modifier string when I used 3 values I'm using as a test input.
Actual when I print the modifier string ```['4', '', '']```
what i should be getting ```['4', '3', '2']```

Comment: Never mind I figured out the issue. It was a leading space in the following two entries.